# Как использовать wildcards при выполнении команд через ssh на лету?

Tags: linux, bash, ssh

Так работает:

```
$ ssh myhost sudo cat /var/log/nginx/access.log | grep 'some pattern'
(получаю нужный мне результат)
```

Но там ротация логов и я хочу поискать во всех. Пытаюсь использовать wildcard:

```
$ ssh myhost sudo cat /var/log/nginx/* | grep 'some pattern'
cat: /var/log/nginx/*: No such file or directory
$ ssh myhost sudo grep 'some pattern' /var/log/nginx/*
grep: /var/log/nginx/*: No such file or directory
```

Похоже, что wildcard пытается раскрыть мой локальный shell. Как обойти это ограничение?

Пробовал брать в кавычки и/или экранировать:

```
$ ssh myhost "sudo grep 'some pattern' /var/log/nginx/*"
grep: /var/log/nginx/*: No such file or directory
$ ssh myhost sudo grep 'some pattern' /var/log/nginx/\*
grep: /var/log/nginx/*: No such file or directory
$ ssh myhost "sudo grep 'some pattern' /var/log/nginx/\*"
grep: /var/log/nginx/*: No such file or directory
```

Если что, на локальной и удаленной машине Ubuntu 14.04, настроен .ssh/config, авторизация по ключу; использую GNU bash, version 4.3.11(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu).

Интересно, что через ansible это работает. Но мне нужно автоматизировать задачу без применения ansible.

```
ansible myhost -i hosts -b -m shell -a 'cat /var/log/nginx/* | grep "some pattern"'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так и работает, вся фишка в кавычках. Ваш локальный bash видит в команде * и интерпретирует локально. А вам нужно передать * на удалённую машину.

Можно взять команду целиком в кавычки `ssh myhost 'sudo cat /var/log/nginx/*'`, можно экранировать: `ssh myhost sudo cat /var/log/nginx/\*`

Но вот у пользователя не оказалось прав читать /var/log/nginx/. Дальше начинается магия на удалённой машине и те же самые грабли, * ловит bash, пытается её обработать сразу сам и не получает доступ к директории. И только потом вызывается sudo. Вызывать сначала sudo и только потом давать bash'у читать * можно как-то так: `ssh myhost sudo bash -c 'cat /var/log/nginx/* | grep "some pattern"'`

Кстати, команда `ssh myhost sudo cat /var/log/nginx/access.log | grep 'some pattern'` делает grep на локальной машине, предварительно передавая все данные. Это может быть весьма нежелательным эффектом. Тогда, опять же, берите команду в кавычки: `ssh myhost "sudo cat /var/log/nginx/access.log | grep 'some pattern'"`. А вообще, grep сам неплохо умеет читать файлы, cat тут и не нужен.

Comment: А в интерактивном режиме работает? Может, у вашего пользователя нет прав читать /var/log/nginx/, соответственно * ловит bash, пробует посмотреть директорию - а у него прав нет. sudo ведь выполняется уже после

Comment: Попробуйте `ssh myhost sudo bash -c 'cat /var/log/nginx/* | grep "some pattern"'`

Comment: Да, так и оказалось. sudo относится к grep, а wildcard явно раскрывается раньше.

Comment: Пока вот что: в интерактивном режиме работает `sudo bash -c ' cat /var/log/nginx/* | grep "some pattern"'`, но не всегда. В некоторых случаях вместо результата выдает `Binary file (standard input) matches
`.

Comment: А вот  с локальной машины `ssh myhost sudo bash -c ...`, кажется, виснет.

Comment: Может быть, у вас там ещё от ротатора *.gz есть?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36497/discussion-between-nick-volynkin-and-).